# Select from other table if exist

Tags: query, union, vertica

hi I want to union 2 tables but I am not sure if the table is exits 
this is my query:

```
select  a from table 
union  
select  case when exists(select a from table1) then (select a from  table1)
else (select a from table2) end;
```

got this

> ERROR: ERROR 4840:  Subquery used as an expression returned more than one row

I need to use limit 1 in a subquery but it's not the result that I wanted.

do you have other suggestions?
thanks

table, for example, I just created them in my local env for testing:

table 1

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 
(
    a int,
    b varchar(80),
    c int
);


CREATE TABLE public.table
    a int,
    b varchar(80),
    c int
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle this won't work, as you can't check if table exists and then join it in a query.

The error is unrelated. You are selecting a value in a subselect and it returns multiple rows, as the table exists.

What you can do is:

- Create temp table
- Check if table1 exists using V_Catalog.table and if specific column existence is important, v_catalog.column
- If it exists, select data from table1 into temp table
- Use the temp table in the union instead of table1

Answer (score -1):

I have not knowledge working with Vertica but you can try using If exists like in SQL Server

If exist (Select 1 FROM sys.objects Where type = 'U' and name in ('YourTableName1', 'YourTableName2')) 
Begin
 Select * From Public.Table1
 Union 
 Select * From Public.Table2
End